# Recuo em parágrafo html

Tags: php, html

Alguém sabe como faço para dar um recuo nas primeiras linhas de cada parágrafo de um texto digitado através de um textarea?

Utilizando a função nl2br do php eu até consigo salvar e exibir o texto com quebra de linha, mas não consigo dar o recuo na primeira linha do parágrafo.

Fazendo desta forma

```
 @php 
   echo '<p style="text-indent: 1.25cm;">'.nl2br($oficio->texto).'</p>'; 
 @endphp
```

ele dá o recuo apenas no primeiro paragrafo, o restante dos parágrafos fica sem o recuo.

Answer (score 3):

Coloque o t`ext-indent` no *container* pai e não diretamente no `<p>`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-indent: 30px;">

  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
  <p>Quam corrupti ipsam molestias consectetur in at exercitationem et porro aut, sint aperiam libero?</p>

</div>
```

**OBS:** Tomando como base o exemplo acima, se vc quiser usar CSS vc pode atacar diretamente cada `<p>`, o resultado será o mesmo do código acima.

```
div > p {
  text-indent: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Os retornos de linha do usuário são armazenados como `\n` no banco de dados e modificados para `<br />` por `nl2br`.

`\n\n` geralmente significa um novo parágrafo (enter). O espaço em branco entre os parágrafos é CSS e, na verdade, é o estilo padrão do navegador. `\n` é um `<br>`(shift + enter).

Então não use o `nl2br()` e faça você mesmo:

```
$texto = '<p>' . htmlspecialchars($text) . '</p>'; // HTML ENCODE
$texto = preg_replace('#\n\n\n*#', '</p><p>', $text); // 2 ou mais \n
$texto = preg_replace('#\n#', '<br />', $text); // tudo sobrando \n
$texto = preg_replace('#><#', ">\n<", $text); // Se você gosta de </p>\n<p> com uma nova linha entre eles.
```